# Is the name 'Clitterhouse' in 'The Amazing Doctor Clitterhouse' a rude joke?

Tags: title, the-amazing-dr-clitterhouse

Ever since seeing the *The Amazing Doctor Clitterhouse*, I have wondered if clitterhouse, which can easily be pronounced as *clitoris*, is a way to sneak a 'vulgar' word into a movie title.

Clitterhouse doesn't seem to appear very much as this instance of the last name of a fictional caharacter and the name of a London development.

Answer (score 3):

### Highly unlikely

The movie is based on a story and stage play of the same name...

> ...written by short-story writer Barré Lyndon, which ran for three months on Broadway with Cedric Hardwicke after playing in London.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Dr._Clitterhouse)</sup>

Given that the film was produced in 1938 it would have fallen under the strict Motion Picture Production Code ("Hays Code") which, if there had been even a hint of "immorality" or innuendo, would have required a name change.

> ...Under Hays' leadership, the MPPDA, later known as the Motion Picture Association of America (MPAA), **adopted the Production Code in 1930 and began strictly enforcing it in 1934.** The Production Code spelled out what was acceptable and what was unacceptable content for motion pictures produced for a public audience in the United States.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Production_Code)</sup>